# Find linear mapping in basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let A:
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}
be a matrix associated with the linear mapping T in the basis B={(1,1,1), (0,2,2), (0,0,3)}.

Find the standard matrix for T.

If I'm not misunderstanding:
We want to find the transformation T in the standard basis. I.e. what the transformation would be with the following basis vectors:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
Currently the transformation T has done a transformation T on A under the basis B.

I'm not sure how think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to start thinking about it. I'll use $\mathcal B$ to denote the coordinate representation in the basis $\mathcal B = \left\{(1,1,1),(0,2,2),(0,0,3) \right\}$ and $\mathcal S$ to denote the coordinate representation in the standard basis. The transformation matrix for the basis $\mathcal B$ is given by 
$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&2&3 \end{array} \right].$$ 
This tells you that the first basis vector in $\mathcal B$ is mapped to the third basis vector in $\mathcal B$, the second is mapped to two times the third, and so on. That is,

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&2&3 \end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal B} = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal B} = (1)\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\3 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal S},$

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&2&3 \end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal B} = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\2 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal B} = (2)\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\3 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal S}, \text{ and }$

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&2&3 \end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal B} = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\3 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal B} = (1)\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\2\\2 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal S} + (3)\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\3 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal S}.$

So you see that *in the standard basis* 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
T \text{ maps } & (1,1,1) \text{ to } (0,0,3), \\ 
T \text{ maps } & (0,2,2) \text{ to } (0,0,6), \\ 
T \text{ maps } & (0,0,3) \text{ to } (0,2,11). 
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

Now see if you can use this information to construct the matrix for $T$ in the standard basis.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I understand still, however. T is a transformation (of what?). B is a basis (of what?) etc. Or in other words, how do they relate to each other. What does it mean that A is the transformation matrix B?

Comment: A *linear transformation* is a linear mapping (or function) between vector spaces. For finite-dimensional vector spaces, every linear transformation between vector spaces can be represented by a matrix. What this matrix looks like will depend on the basis that it is acting on. Take a look at this video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=3

Answer (score 0):

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&2&0\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$
is the change-of-basis matrix from the basis defined by $B$'s columns to the standard basis. $T$ in the standard basis must be similar to $A$, and is in fact $BAB^{-1}$, which works out to
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&-2/3&2/3\\0&-2/3&11/3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is meant by "B is the change-of-basis matrix from the basis defined by B's columns".

Comment: @badatmaths Viewed as a linear transformation, the matrix $B$ takes vectors expressed in its basis coordinates and turns them into coordinates for the standard basis.